# Array modification in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a function to change the following array (basically to remove “str” and “=>” and “value”)

```
[{"str"=>"abc", "value"=>1}, {"str"=>"efg", "value"=>2}, {"str"=>"hij", "value"=>3}]
```

to something like this:

```
[[abc, 1], [efg, 2], [hij,3]]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the array you gave.

```
orig_arr.map {|hash| [hash['str'], hash['value']]}
```

If you want a general solution, you'll have to specify more requirements. A hash's entries are not ordered (well, they do maintain order in ruby 1.9, but it's not good practice to rely on this), so you can't simply grab the values via `hash.values`, unless you really don't care about the ordering.

Comment: @joe please click the checkbox next to my answer if it sufficiently answers your question. Thanks.